# Executor Service and Main Thread not executing in parallel

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, executorservice

I have a requirement that both Main thread and Executor service should execute in parallel. Main thread should not wait for all threads in executor service to finish. It should continue its execution while executor service is executing its threads.
Example Main Method

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    String mess = "test completed";
    //Start of ExecutorService - ThreadPool of size 500
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(500);
    //Creating 500 tasks to execute
    List<AsyncTask> callables = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=1 ; i<= 500 ; i++){
        callables.add(new AsyncTask(i));
    }
    //Submitting all 500 tasks to execute
    List<Future<String>> futures = executorService.invokeAll(callables);
    for(Future<String> future : futures){
        System.out.println("future.get = " + future.get());
    }
    executorService.shutdown();
    //End of Executor service

    //Below code executes only when executor service is finished.
    //I want below code to execute in parallel with executor service
    //Means It should print this mess before executor service finishes
    System.out.println(mess);
}
```

Callable Task

```java
public class AsyncTask implements Callable<String>{
    private int i;
    public AsyncTask(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }
    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        return "Task " +i;
    }
}
```

OutPut :

```java
future.get = Task 1
future.get = Task 2
future.get = Task 3
future.get = Task 4
.......continues till
future.get = Task 500
test completed
```

Expected output :

test completed message to be printed during some async tasks are finished or before start of async tasks

Sample output

```java
future.get = Task 1
future.get = Task 2
test completed       // Both Main method and Executor service is running in parallel
future.get = Task 3
...........
future.get = Task 500
```

I have not worked on Threads before, do i miss something ? whole idea of using executor service is to execute some tasks in parallel with main thread right ?
Please suggest me to fix this

Answer (score 0):

`ExecutorService.invokeAll` will wait until all task was completed, so all code after it would not be executed until `ExecutorService.invokeAll` was returned. Put the service execution code to another thread will simply solve the problem.

```java
class RunService extends Thread {
    RunService () {
    }

    public void run() {
        //Start of ExecutorService - ThreadPool of size 500
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(500);
        //Creating 500 tasks to execute
        List<AsyncTask> callables = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=1 ; i<= 500 ; i++){
            callables.add(new AsyncTask(i));
        }
        //Submitting all 500 tasks to execute
        List<Future<String>> futures = executorService.invokeAll(callables);
        for(Future<String> future : futures){
            System.out.println("future.get = " + future.get());
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        //End of Executor service
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    String mess = "test completed";

    RunService rs = new RunService();
    rs.Start();

    //Below code executes only when executor service is finished.
    //I want below code to execute in parallel with executor service
    //Means It should print this mess before executor service finishes
    System.out.println(mess);
}
```

Comment: I don't think they completed immediately. I have increase size from 500 to 500000 still result is same test completed prints after 500000 completes

Comment: @Rohit Just use `Thread.sleep(1) ` in you `AsyncTask.call` method, you will see the difference.

Comment: @Rohit Sorry, I didn't read you code carefully enough. I will Edit my answer.